# Steel vs iron for linear solenoid plunger

Tags: solenoid, electromagnetic

How much more force would an iron plunger provide than a steel plunger? From what I’ve read it seems like it would be much better, but I have no idea where to buy an iron rod.

Also, how much of an effect does the material of the frame of the solenoid have on the force?

Comment: Hints: what are the equations telling you? What factor would you have to look up for steel and iron?

Comment: @Transistor I’m comparing the magnetic permeability of the two materials but I only know how they are relevant for a normal electromagnet with a fixed core. What I don’t understand is how those factors influence the force when there is no longer that fixed central core but instead a moving plunger and a fixed frame.

Comment: The relative permeability depends on the iron content and if annealed in Nitrogen (uncommon).   You can test it by the pull strength with a small magnet.   A scrap yard might be friendly to supporting a student with a sample for a school project.  The more iron, the easier it rusts. But a spray coating to slow that down.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)#Values_for_some_common_materials  The energy stored and force is in the air gap so a large gap to frame contributes very little.  The interesting part is a Neodymium magnet is about the same permeability as air.

Comment: This depends hugely on the construction -- so show us.  It doesn't take much of an air gap for the force to be dominated by that gap rather than the plunger material.